# Check if an array has a key without a value, then do this (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key-value

Say I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 2017-01-01 00:00:00
)
```

How can I dynamically check to see if the area has any empty values?

Comment: `foreach($array as $arr){ if($arr==""){echo "null value";}else{echo $arr;}}`

or You can simply use `print_r(array_filter($linksArray));` Because array_filter() method removes the empty.

Comment: So what do you mean by _check_?  Remove if empty?  Get the index?  Play a sound if empty, what?

Comment: 4 answers, none accepted? did you found your solution?

Comment: Sorry, you answered my question but I think at the time the site wasn't letting my accept your answer. Fixed now- thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
$array = [
  null, 
  '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
  '',
  [],
  # etc..
];

foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(empty($value)){
    echo "$key is empty";
  }
}
```

See the [type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information.

Comment: why we need key value pair for this kind of array, cant you simply do `foreach($array as $a){ if($a==""){ echo "empty"}}`

Comment: Because the OP asked: "*check to see if the area*", assuming he is referring to an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if it has any empty values by comparing the array values to the result of `array_filter` (which removes empty values.)

```
$has_empty_values = $array != array_filter($array);
```

Comment: So compare to `array_values($array)` or compare counts.

Comment: Wait, array_filter _does_ preserve keys :( oops

Comment: I want to check if any key has value or null and  this `array_filter()` works for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
// $array = [ ... ];

$count = count($array);

for( $i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
    if( $array[$count] == 0 ){
         // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: @aesede thanks for sorting this out. coding on an ipad is a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

For this you have more possibility:

1. You can use `array_filter` function without without a second parameter

   `array_filter([ 'empty' => null, 'test' => 'test']);`

but for this be carful because this remove all values which are equal false (null, false, 0)

2. You can use `array_filter` function with callback function:

   ```
   function filterEmptyValue( $value ) {
       return ! empty( $value );
   }

   array_filter([ 'empty' => null, 'test' => 'test'], 'filterEmptyValue');
   ```
3. You can use foreach or for:

   ```
   $array = ['empty' => null, 'test' => 'test'];

   foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       if(empty($value)) {
           unset($array[$key]);
       }
   }

   $array = [null, 'test'];

   for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
       if(empty($array[$i])) {
           unset($array[$i]);
       }
   }
   ```

   This is samples so you must think and make good solution for your problem